# Around the world in one day

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, relative-motion

in the novel " Around the world in 80 days· they manage to get an extra day because they go from london to the East

so my question is , what would happened if we could fly around the world at constant speed but in one day

if i start at Greenwich meridian on monday at 00:00 hours and it takes me only a day to get around the world then when i arrive at london again what hour would be? would be still 0:00 hours monday?

Comment: Is this a question about physics? I don't think it is. It seems to be an entirely mathematical exercise and it is *off topic* according to the homework policy : it shows no effort and it does not ask about a physics concept.

Comment: If it takes you exactly 24 hours to reach your starting point, it will be exactly 24 hours later! You don't need to worry about time-zones.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. Imagine a line (Line A) moving continuously from East to West. Now, on the Eastern side of it, its Monday and on the Western its Sunday. Now, picture another line (Line B), exactly opposite to it.

Now what happens if you take off from that line (while Monday) and travel more than half the circumference in less than 12hrs? You would be to the West of Line A but to the East of Line B. If you remember how the line works, you'd find that you've arrived while its still Sunday.

Now, what if you cont. this way? What if you flew even further? 2 Things will happen. First, the moment you cross Line A, it'd be Monday. If you decide to stop and complicate your life no further, great! If not, oh well...
 Everytime you cross Line A, you will advance a day but later than people at line B which is not how it was supposed to happen if you just stayed at home and watched Ye Olde Favourito Showwe.